# Creating Eventbridge rule on S3 Cloudtrail API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-event-bridge

I want to create an Eventbridge rule for S3 Policy change event.
After researching for a while I got to know that for this, Rule pattern should be created for  Cloudtrail API.
I created the rule with below pattern -

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"]
  }
}
```

I attached SNS as a target to this rule, which has my email id as subscription.
But while testing(Adding/Deleting bucket policy), I can see that rule is not getting triggered as I am not able to receive any mails from target SNS.
Can someone let me know If the rule pattern is correct ?
Also I checked in Cloudtrail, I was able to see api events getting generated for **PutBucketPolicy** and **DeleteBucketPolicy**

Answer (score 1):

The EventBridge rule that you mentioned is correct and sufficient to route all the CloudTrail S3 Events, including `PutBucketPolicy` and `DeleteBucketPolicy`, to the designated SNS topic.

However, by default, CloudTrail does not send bucket-level events to EventBridge.
To publish those management events to EventBridge, you need to [create an active trail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-create-a-trail-using-the-console-first-time.html) and that will ensure the events are published to EventBridge. Once the trail is set up, the EventBridge rule you created will effectively route the bucket-level events to the specified SNS topic.

Answer (score -1):

The event pattern mentioned in the question was not correct.
Following worked for me -

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutBucketPolicy",
      "DeleteBucketPolicy"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": ["<bucket_name_goes_here>"]
      }
  }
}
```